# python unsupported operand type issue

Tags: python

I'm writing a user interface for a golf round where there is a text file with the players' names in the league.  The user enters each player's scores for 9 holes and the gross score, the pars, and the birdies for each player is returned.  I'm receiving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/tinydancer9454/Documents/python/golfRound.py", line 101, in main
    enterScores(l, players)
  File "/Users/tinydancer9454/Documents/python/golfRound.py", line 114, in enterScores
    p.recordScores(holeScores)
  File "/Users/tinydancer9454/Documents/python/golfRound.py", line 42, in recordScores
    self.__gross = sum(holeScores)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I don't really know how to fix it because I'm not supposed to be changing the Player or League class.

```
class Player:
""" Represents a player in the golf league """

    PAR = [4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 5]
    """ par for each of the 9 holes """

    def __init__(self, name):
        """ creates a Player and keeps track of stats """
        self.__name = name
        self.__pars = 0
        self.__birdies = 0
        self.__gross = 0

    def getName(self):
        """ returns a player's name """
        return self.__name

    def getGross(self):
        """ returns a player's gross score """
        return self.__gross

    def getPars(self):
        """ returns number of pars made """
        return self.__pars

    def getBirdies(self):
        """ returns number of birdies made """
        return self.__birdies

    def recordScores(self, holeScores):
        """ mutator method that uses the results of one round of play
          (9 holes) to update a player's stats """
        self.__gross = sum(holeScores)
        self.__findparsandbirdies(holeScores)

    def __findparsandbirdies(self, scores):
        """ helper method that finds the number of pars and birdies """

        pars = 0
        birdies = 0
        hole = 0
        for score in scores:
            if score == Player.PAR[hole]:
                pars += 1
            if score == Player.PAR[hole] - 1:
                birdies += 1
            hole += 1
        self.__pars = pars
        self.__birdies = birdies

    def __str__(self):
        """ returns a string representation of a player """
        return 'a Player named ' + self.__name

class League:
""" represents the players of a golf league """

    def __init__(self, fileName = 'players.txt'):
        """ creates a list of Player objects from the
            names stored in the file specified """
        self.__playerList = []
        datafile = open(fileName, 'r')
        for line in datafile:
            playerName = line.rstrip()
            player = Player(playerName)
            self.__playerList.append(player)

    def getNumPlayers(self):
        """ returns the number of players is the league """
        return len(self.__playerList)

    def getPlayerbyPosition(self, position):
        """ returns the player at the specified position """
        return self.__playerList[position]

    def getPlayerbyName(self, name):
        """ returns the player with the specified name """
        for player in self.__playerList:
            if player.getName() == name:
                return player
        return None

    def __str__(self):
        return 'a golf league with ' + str(self.getNumPlayers()) + ' players'



def main():
    """The input and output for the program"""
    l= League()
    players= []
    enterScores(l, players, position)
    isValidScore(holeScores)
    output(players)


def enterScores(l, players, position):
    """enter the scores"""
    for position in range(l.getNumPlayers()):
        holeScores= input(("Please enter a list of the player's scores: "))
        while not isValidScore(holeScores):
            holeScores= input(("Please enter a valid list of scores: "))
        p= l.getPlayerbyPosition(position)
        players.append(p)
        p.recordScores(holeScores)


def isValidScore(holeScores):
    """checks if the scores entered for a single hole are 1 to 10, inclusive"""
    for score in holeScores:
        if score == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 or 10:
            return True
        else:
            return False                


def output(grossScore, pars, birdies):
    """prints output"""
    for player in players:
        print(player.getName())
        print('Gross score:', player.getGross())
        print('Pars: ', player.getPars())
        print('Birdies: ', player.getBirdies())
```

Comment: It looks like you are passing in a mixed list of strings and integers, which python complains it can't add together.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 3, `holeScores` is a string, not an integer. You need to turn it into a list of numbers:

```
user_input = input("Please enter a valid list of scores: ")
holeScores = [int(score) for score in user_input.split()]
```

Also, this line does not do what you think it does:

```
if score == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 or 10:
```

It'll be evaluated like:

```
if (score == 1) or (2) or ...
```

Which will evaluate to `True`. Just do this instead:

```
for score in scores:
    if not (1 <= score  <= 10):
        return False

return True
```

Comment: Thank you that makes sense.  However it is now giving me an invalid syntax error and highlighting 'while' of the while loop.  Does it need to be indented differently now?

Comment: @tinydancer9454: What's the full traceback?

Comment: That loop is fine. However, it's basically a by-hand version of the built-in [`all()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all). With that you could write just `all(1 <= score <= 10 for score in holeScores)`.

Comment: @blender  I fixed the syntax error but now I'm getting this: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#24>", line 1, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/tinydancer9454/Documents/python/golfRound.py", line 101, in main
    enterScores(l, players)`

Comment: `File "/Users/tinydancer9454/Documents/python/golfRound.py", line 111, in enterScores
    while not isValidScore(holeScores):
  File "/Users/tinydancer9454/Documents/python/golfRound.py", line 119, in isValidScore
    for score in holeScores:
  File "/Users/tinydancer9454/Documents/python/golfRound.py", line 110, in <genexpr>
    holeScores= (int(score) for score in inputScore.split())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3,6,4,5,3,7,4,3,2'`

Comment: @tinydancer9454: `.split()` splits on whitespace (i.e. spaces). Use `.split(',')` to split on commas.